# Cannot figure out how to chain nested promise with Q

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm new into node.js and promise (Q), so please be kind.
I want to chain nested promises with his executing parent chain and i can't find how to.

I've made a toy script to illustrate my pb, you can launch it with node.js :

```
var Q = require("q");

function init() {
    return {nbIn: 0, nbOut: 0, stop: false};
}

function fn1(ctx) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    console.log("fn1:" + JSON.stringify(ctx));
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("fn1: resolve");
        deferred.resolve(ctx);
    }, 1000)

    return deferred.promise;
}

function sub1(ctx) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    console.log("sub1:" + JSON.stringify(ctx));
    setTimeout(function() {
        ++ctx.nbIn;
        console.log("sub1: resolve");
        deferred.resolve(ctx);
    }, 1000);

    return deferred.promise;
}

function sub2(ctx) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    console.log("sub2:" + JSON.stringify(ctx));
    setTimeout(function() {
        ++ctx.nbOut;
        if(ctx.nbOut === 3) {
            console.log("sub2: resolve");
            ctx.stop = true;
            deferred.resolve(ctx);
        }
        else {
            console.log("sub2: promise");
            return sub1(ctx).then(sub2);
        }
    }, 1000);

    return deferred.promise;
}

function fn2(ctx) {
    console.log("fn2:" + JSON.stringify(ctx));
    return sub1(ctx).then(sub2);
}

function fn3(ctx) {
    console.log("fn3:" + JSON.stringify(ctx));
}

Q.fcall(init).then(fn1).then(fn2).then(fn3);
```

It display:

```
fn1:{"nbIn":0,"nbOut":0,"stop":false}
fn1: resolve
fn2:{"nbIn":0,"nbOut":0,"stop":false}
sub1:{"nbIn":0,"nbOut":0,"stop":false}
sub1: resolve
sub2:{"nbIn":1,"nbOut":0,"stop":false}
sub2: promise
sub1:{"nbIn":1,"nbOut":1,"stop":false}
sub1: resolve
sub2:{"nbIn":2,"nbOut":1,"stop":false}
sub2: promise
sub1:{"nbIn":2,"nbOut":2,"stop":false}
sub1: resolve
sub2:{"nbIn":3,"nbOut":2,"stop":false}
sub2: resolve
```

I would like to chain the last line `sub2` with `fn3`.

Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> setTimeout(function() {
>     …
>     return sub1(ctx).then(sub2);
> }, …)
> ```

Here you're trying to `return` from an asynchronous plain callback. You cannot do that, the result will be lost as `setTimeout` does not care about it.

You can only `return` from `.then()` callbacks. In your case, it would look like this:

```
function sub2(ctx) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    console.log("sub2:" + JSON.stringify(ctx));
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(ctx);
    }, 1000);

    return deferred.promise.then(function(ctx) {
        ++ctx.nbOut;
        if (ctx.nbOut === 3) {
            console.log("sub2: resolve");
            ctx.stop = true;
            return ctx;
        } else {
            console.log("sub2: promise");
            return sub1(ctx).then(sub2);
        }
    });
}
```

You also can see that you're always using `Q.defer` together with a `setTimeout` now. You should make a helper function for that which returns a promise, and [use deferreds as seldom as possible](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Comment: ok, i get it. `setTimeout` just used to simulate real asynchronous functions, like `db.connect` / `query` / `insert`.

Comment: Well, the argument holds for them as well: Wrap them as tight as possible in helper functions (or [create those programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)) that only spit out promises and do no processing. Do all the data manipulation and flow logic with those promises.